# Google Sheets formula generated by a GAS script throws an error, even though it's correct

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a script in GAS that extracts ID from a cluttered entry and then imputs it into a Formula that will look it up in the data sheet - however, the formulas created by the script cause the Google Sheet to throw out an error, as if the formula was faulty. However, using Google Sheets' "Find and Replace" window to replace a character for the same exact character (Like the starting = to =), it's possible to make it accept the formula and run it correctly - manually removing a character, pressing Enter and putting it back in also works.

I have tried implementing Find and Replace in GAS to make it automatic - and while the script works properly and replaces the given character, it doesn't do what the manual Find and Replace does - the formulas already corrected stay working, and the ones that are 'incorrect' are still erroneous.

```
for(var i = 0; i < range.getNumRows(); i++ ){
    //Processing to extract the id
    valsO[i][0]="=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(\""+id+"*\";'Data'!B2:B$8400;1;FALSE));\"NONE\";VLOOKUP(\""+id+"*\";'Data'!B2:B$8400;1;FALSE))";
    }
range=sheet.getRange(range.getRowIndex(), resultColumn, range.getNumRows());
range.setFormulas(valsO);
```

EDIT: Corrected from `.setValues` to `.setFormulas` and from `IFERROR` to `ISERROR` - however, the Formula Parse Error persists, despite working if it is typed in or copy-pasted in.

Comment: If you're setting a formula you should use `.setFormulas()` not `.setValues()`.

Comment: @ross I wasn't aware of that method existing. That's my bad. However, replacing `.setValues()` with `.setFormulas()` did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: @GNUsNotAUser I am not allowed to share the worksheet, as the sheets contain personal information. Sorry

Comment: @PrintSeer are you able to make a copy and remove the personal information so that we can try to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: @ross I will try. However, It'll have to wait until tomorrow. Also, fair warning, a lot of the stuff that's left is in a non-English language

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Questions that looks for help on non-working code should include a [mcve] and enough details to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the making of an anonymised version of the Spreadsheet for everyone to see and check, I accidentally stumbled into the right answer.

My issue was that I was expecting Google Sheets to parse the formulae generated from a script in a non-English language, just like it normally does when typed right into the sheet. Once I actually translated the entire Formula, including the Boolean value FALSE to English, the script started working properly.

Thank you for your help