# #NAME? during google sheet macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using this macro I have as issue #NAME?. Can you help me to solve?

```
  function macro() 
  { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
    { 
     var rowData = data[i]; 
     var parameter1 = rowData[10];
     var parameter2 = rowData[11]; 
     if (parameter1 == "OK" && parameter2 != "OK") 
     { 
       sheet.getRange("M" +(i+1)).activate();
       sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=DATA.VALORE(A' +(i+1)+ ')+7*(6-I' +(i+1)+ ')');
      }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please share a sample spreadsheet file so that we can precisely reproduce your issue a as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Also the DATA.VALORE (or DATEVALUE) function produces the  #NAME? error because it cannot identify range (6-I' +(i+1)) & I'm unable to fully understand this part. Please share the desired result that you want to see with the DATA.VALORE function, like show us a sample desired result.

Comment: DATA.VALORE requires a string, see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=it here is my spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ev7yrIgA4uj8M-aqGkRoeEBZA07A176xX46cmGvmlk4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

When using Google Sheets macros (Google Apps Script) to write formulas, functions should be written in English.

This was learned from experience. There isn't official documentation about this.

Related

- [Google Sheets formula generated by a GAS script throws an error, even though it's correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58098585/1595451)

Answer (score -1):

#### Error:

`DATA.VALORE` is not a valid function name, thus it shows `#NAME`. Use valid  function names.

[image: sample]

If you were meaning to use [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en), then use it instead.

That would yield into a number like `44928`, use [`TO_DATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239?hl=en) or format that column to `DATE` instead of automatic to convert that back to date.

#### Code:

- `sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(A' + (i + 1) + ')+7*(6-I' + (i + 1) + '))');`

#### Output:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Formula parse errors](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/formula-parse-error/)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en)
- [TO_DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239?hl=en)